# Performance issue after bridging between mosuitto and AWS IoT core

Tags: amazon-web-services, mosquitto, aws-iot-core

We have Mosquitto broker and AWS IoT core. Our old systems are connected with Mosquitto broker. Now, We have introduced AWS IoT core for new architecture. So we have bridge between Mosuitto broker and AWS IoT core. It is working fine in lesser amount of messages. But we have tried with 2500 messages at a time by using Jmeter. It is executed in 11 seconds. all are success. But in AWS IoT core its received only 369 messages. It is varying in each execution but it will be around 1000.

my bridge configuration is

```
connection awsiot
address <iot core endpoint>:8883
topic flow out 1
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_insecure false
cleansession true
clientid bridgeawsiot-client
start_type automatic
notifications false
log_type all
bridge_cafile <Path to the rootCA>
bridge_certfile <Path to the PEM encoded client certificate>
bridge_keyfile <Path to the PEM encoded client private key>
```

How can resolve this issue?